# session is not destroyed

Tags: php, session, logout

i have this file

secure.php

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
    header("Location:emprego.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:emprego.php");
}

$name = $_SESSION['u_name'];

?>

<li><?php echo "<a href='emprego.php?logout' id='D'>Logout</a>";?></li>
```

basically, if i do logout, i will be redirected to emprego.php. But if i click in back page button (arrow in browser), i can view the same page (secure.php).

my question is, why?

thanks

Comment: Have you checked your php.ini to see if you have session automatically starting? I would imagine this is your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are not viewing a cached version of the page? Also, use exit() after any redirect, otherwise PHP continue to execute the page and if your browser do not follow the location header, it will display the content.

Comment: Can you do anything on the page after logging out? Could just be a cache error, meaning they could view the page since it is being loaded from their local history. In this case, they shouldn't be able to do anything from there, trying to change pages would give you session errors (assuming you check for sessions before allowing a user to perform an action).

Comment: Back page button I presume refers to the browser button. I think you are getting the page from the browser cache, rather than the server. So hit refresh to see if you session is valid or not.

Comment: I cleared the cache but the page still opens

Comment: well... this href='emprego.php?logout >>> must be href='secure.php?logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Take a look at example 1 here. It clearly states that you have to clear $_SESSION as well.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['u_name']); //makes it non-existent (it does unset) that variable
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:emprego.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser keeps a copy of the page in cache. When you click the back button, you are seeing the local cached copy, not the current page from the server. If your security is set up properly, you will not be able to do anything meaningful from that cached page.

It is for this reason that secure websites (bank sites, for example) tell you to log off and clear your cache (or close the browser) after you log out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using session cookies, also try expiring the session cookie explicitly, like this:

```
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
```

Also, going back in the browser only loads a cached copy of the page.  If you tried interacting with the cached page to fetch a new page from the server, you shouldn't be able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found `header_remove();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

```
    Caution: This function will remove all headers set by PHP, including cookies, session and the X-Powered-By headers.
```

Not sure whether this is the appropriate way to do it, but it's pretty effective for log out functionality.

Answer (score 0):

All the other solutions didn't seem to work for me. However, this workaround did the trick. Basically, the code below keeps calling the logout until the logout finally succeeds:

```
if (isset($_GET["logout"])){
    if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
        unset($_SESSION["username"]);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:/?logout=true");
        exit;
    }
    header("Location:/");
    exit;
}
```