# SESSION not getting destroyed

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

```
<?php
session_start();

$twoDaysBack = time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
setcookie('Email', '', $twoDaysBack);

$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("Location:Home.php");
exit();
 ?>
```

I realise this is a duplicate, however all the other questions didnt seem to help me. So my problem is even though i logout the cookies get deleted but the PHPSESID in inspect >> Resources >> Cookies window. Please help because i will be checking for if isset session id in all my pages. Please let me know if i need to include any more code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6427466/870729 - your code is fine.  Note that you don't HAVE anything in `$_SESSION`, so not sure what the concern is.  Would be different if you had values, such as `$_SESSION['something'] = "my value";`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, there was an answer there that helped me, my browser creates a cached copy of the session and it worked like the session wasnt even there. Thanks alot though